# ADF partialSubmit lifecycle

Tags: oracle-adf

Does autosubmit and partialsubmit send an AJAX request or normal request to server? How do the components which has its partialTrigger property set get refreshed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Shay's answer..

If you use a browser debugger like Firebug, you can tell how partial submits that cause PPR work by monitoring the RQ/RS data. PPR responses typically contain the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<?Adf-Rich-Response-Type ?>
<content action="/YOURAPPLICATION/faces/somthing/SomePage?_adf.ctrl-state=1d72fpsv6l_20">    
   <!-- zero to N fragments -->
   <fragment>
       <!--HTML content here which may include javascript as well -->
   </fragment>
</content>
```

During a PPR's render phase, the renderer actually tries to render only those that are partial triggered but the whole component tree is still restored.

Comment: I checked with FireBug and it show partialsubmit is AJAX rquest and server sendsback data to update on client.Thanks all of you for your comments

Comment: If you are satisfied with one of the answers here, please mark it as correct.